# Jest - mock a function being called from the function under test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a utils.js file with a function that calls another function in the same file. Like this:

```
// utils.js    
async function originalFunc (params) {
    ...

    await anotherFunc(arg1, arg2)
}
```

In another file I'm using jest to test the `originalFunc`

```
// utils.test.js
test('should test orginalFunc', async () => {
    const params = {
        arg1: 'data1',
        arg2: 'data2',
    }

    const anotherFunc = jest.fn()

    await util.originalFunc(params)

    // todo: expect anotherFunc to be called with correct params
})
```

However when using this configuration the real `anotherFunc` is being called rather than the mock `jest.fn()` version.

I've also tried mocking the module like this:

```
jest.mock('../src/util', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('../src/util'),
    anotherFunc: jest.fn(),
}));
```

But that does not work either.

How can I force `originalFunc` to use a mocked implementation of `anotherFunc`?

Comment: There's an argument to suggest that you can't test this by design - in any other language you wouldn't typically unit test private methods. Wouldn't validating the result be just as good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep same reference for `anotherFunc` function using `exports.anotherFunc`. Then, you can use `jest.spyOn()` to mock it.

E.g.

`utils.js`:

```js
async function originalFunc(params) {
  await exports.anotherFunc(params.arg1, params.arg2);
}

async function anotherFunc(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log('real anotherFunc implementation');
}

exports.originalFunc = originalFunc;
exports.anotherFunc = anotherFunc;
```

`utils.test.js`:

```js
const utils = require('./utils');

describe('67189137', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const params = {
      arg1: 'data1',
      arg2: 'data2',
    };
    const anotherFuncSpy = jest
      .spyOn(utils, 'anotherFunc')
      .mockImplementation(() => console.log('mock anotherFunc implementation'));
    await utils.originalFunc(params);
    expect(anotherFuncSpy).toBeCalledWith('data1', 'data2');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67189137/utils.test.js (8.324 s)
  67189137
    ✓ should pass (20 ms)

  console.log
    mock anotherFunc implementation

      at Object.<anonymous> (examples/67189137/utils.test.js:11:41)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.347 s
```

Another way is using dependency injection, pass the `anotherFunc` as a parameter to `originalFunc` function like this:

```js
async function originalFunc(params, anotherFunc) {
  await anotherFunc(params.arg1, params.arg2);
}
```